# How to Refresh a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

so I want to make some sort of Tic tac toe, and I'm not sure if the rest of my code is correct (I'm obviously not done yet) but I think that the Problem is that the `JFrame` doesn't Refresh and I don't know how to do that so how to Refresh a frame?

```
package pack1;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Gui {


public  Gui() {
     Var.jf = new JFrame();
      Var.jf.setSize(Var.screenwidth, Var.screenheight);

      Var.button1 = new JButton(Var.arr[Var.a]);
      Var.jf.add(Var.button1);
      Var.button2 = new JButton(Var.arr[Var.b]);
      Var.jf.add(Var.button2);
      Var.button3 = new JButton(Var.arr[Var.c]);
      Var.jf.add(Var.button3);
      Var.button4 = new JButton(Var.arr[Var.d]);
      Var.jf.add(Var.button4);
      Var.button5 = new JButton(Var.arr[Var.e]);
      Var.jf.add(Var.button5);
      Var.button6 = new JButton(Var.arr[Var.f]);
      Var.jf.add(Var.button6);
      Var.button7 = new JButton(Var.arr[Var.g]);
      Var.jf.add(Var.button7);
      Var.button8 = new JButton(Var.arr[Var.h]);
      Var.jf.add(Var.button8);
      Var.button9 = new JButton(Var.arr[Var.i]);
      Var.jf.add(Var.button9);
      Var.jf.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,10,10));
      Var.button1.addActionListener(new KeyListiner());

      Var.jf.setTitle("Tic tac toe");
      Var.jf.setVisible(true);
      Var.jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Var.jf.setLayout(null);
      Var.jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      Var.jf.setResizable(false);
   }
}
```

---

```
 package pack1;

 import javax.swing.*;

 public class Var {
 static JFrame jf;
 static JButton button1;
 static JButton button2;
 static JButton button3;
 static JButton button4;
 static JButton button5;
 static JButton button6;
 static JButton button7;
 static JButton button8;
 static JButton button9;
 static  int a = 2;
 static  int b = 2;
 static int c = 2;
 static int d = 2;
 static int e = 2;
 static int f = 2;
 static int g = 2;
 static int h = 2;
 static int i = 2;

 static int screenwidth = 900, screenheight = 900;
 static String[]arr = new String[3];{

 arr[0] = "X";
 arr[1] = "O";
 arr[2] = " ";
 }}
```

---

```
package pack1;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class KeyListiner implements ActionListener {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==Var.button1);
    
     
     System.out.println(Var.a);
     Var.a= 0 ;
     
}
}
```

If I didn't explained something correctly or something like this just tell me.

Comment: Please update your question to state what the problem is.

Comment: Create a model for the state of the came. Add a method that accepts a `GameModel` and updates the content / state of the components to match the model. When it comes time to refresh, create a blank  initial model and call the method. **General tips:** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) ..

Comment: .. and use it consistently. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 5) `static JFrame jf;` Don't make components or windows `static` unless you can justify why they *have* to be static. It typically causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: .. 6) `public class KeyListiner implements ActionListener {` Use meaningful and relevant names for classes, methods and attributes. Also avoid **misleading** names. This is a good example. There is such a thing as a `KeyListener` which listens .. for keystrokes. An `ActionListener` is meant for either keyboard or mouse actions on 'actionable' components like buttons, menus or text fields.

Answer (score 0):

You may have several buttons but ony one of them has a keylistener.
That means you would have to move the focus to the one button and press a key.
Tricky as the UI does not indicate such a limitation.

Try to take this with an event-driven approach. Attach an ActionListener to every button. Inside this actionlistener you change the board as required, then call the repaint() method (that does not really repaint but mark this component to be repainted), and EXIT your method. Unless you exit the method which is running on the Event Dispatcher Thread no UI updates will happen.

If you want to continue doing your stuff while the UI updates you need to create your own Thread.